# I somehow cant display the information entered in the text form field. Is there any problem with my code?

Tags: flutter

I am testing out my sign-in page code if I can capture and print the data entered into the text form field. However, it could not display both the email and password text form field data. Instead, it can only print out the data from the text form field that was lastly edited/entered. The other will be displayed as nothing. I can't seem to find any problems with my code either. Please help me out.

Here are my input and the output results:
[SignInInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjCjl.png)
[SignInOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mamlu.png)

With almost similar code, my sign up page worked just fine:
[SignUpInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfyyn.png)
[SignUpOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfrTc.png)

Below is the code for my sign in page:

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {

  //Text field state
  String email = '';
  String password = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Form(
            child: ListView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 30.0,
                    right: 30.0,
                    top: 10.0,
                    bottom: 10.0,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() => email = val);
                    },
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                      labelText: 'Email',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 30.0,
                    right: 30.0,
                    top: 10.0,
                    bottom: 10.0,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() => email = val);
                    },
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                      labelText: 'Password',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 10.0,
                      right: 10.0,
                      top: 10.0,
                      bottom: 10.0,
                    ),
                    child: CheckboxListTile(
                      value: true,
                      title: Text("Keep me signed in to receive chat messages!"),
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    )
                ),

                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 30.0,
                    right: 30.0,
                    top: 10.0,
                    bottom: 10.0,
                  ),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: FlatButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 12.0,
                        bottom: 12.0,
                      ),
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () async {
                        print(email);
                        print(password);
                      },
                      child: Text('Sign In'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.0,
                    bottom: 10.0,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Text(
                        'Forgot Password',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: (){},
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign the changed text from TextFormField only to the **email** property

```
//...
                  child: TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() => email = val);
                    },
//...
                  child: TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() => email = val);
                    },
//...
```

so just change the second one to :

```
                  child: TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() => password = val);
                    },
```